# Convert 0.0 to 0 in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, decimal, rounding

I want to write a spark sql query to convert the numbers as below:

```
9.82000 --> 9.82
40183.14 -> 40183.14
03234.00 -> 3234
0.0     --> 0
```

> Round() with specific decimal places returns the trailing zeroes as it is (like 9.8200). trim(round())+0 removes trailing zeroes but fails for 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [rtrim](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#rtrim) zeroes, then decimal point.

```
spark.sql("""WITH numbers AS (
               SELECT explode(array(9.8200, 40183.14, 03234.00, 0.0)) as n
             )
             SELECT rtrim('.', rtrim('0', n)) as formatted
               FROM numbers
          """).show
+---------+
|formatted|
+---------+
|     9.82|
| 40183.14|
|     3234|
|        0|
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a [case](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp). Basically an if/else.

For this example the column is `value`.

```
select
  case
  when value = 0.0 then 0
  else round(value, 2)
  end
from...
```